# Typescript adding types to EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to make my code more readable and concise.

The biggest problem I am currently having is with the `EventEmitter` class. Every time I create a new class that uses `EventEmitter` I have to declare all the functions of the `EventEmitter` to make the class easier to understand and use.

Ex:

```
interface Hello {
    addListener(event: 'hi', listener: (message: string) => void): this;
    on(event: 'hi', listener: (message: string) => void): this;
    ...
}

class Hello extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() { super(); }
}
```

I have searched around for a solution but I couldn't find anything that suits me so I tryed to come up with my own.

```
interface EventEmitterEvents {
    [event: string]: any[];
}

interface EventEmitterType<T extends EventEmitterEvents> extends EventEmitter {
    addListener<K extends keyof T>(event: K, listener: (...args: T[K]) => void): this;
    on<K extends keyof T>(event: K, listener: (...args: T[K]) => void): this;
    ...
}

class Hello extends EventEmitter implements EventEmitterType<{'hi': [string]}> { ... }
```

But when I try to implement the interface *EventEmitterType* it throws an error

`types of property 'addListener' are incompatible`

I have figured out that for some reason in the `'addListener'` and functions alike, type `event` is said to be `'string' | 'symbol' | 'number'` which **is** incompatible with the `EventEmitter` where it is `'string' | 'symbol'` but in the `EventEmitterEvents` I have defined that event is of type `'string'`.

Question:
Is there any way to fix this, and if not, is there any other way of recreating this functionality (not having to type all those functions)?

Edit:
If I set event argument to `'string'` it will still throw error because of listener which is also incompatible with `addListener` saying `'any[]' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'`.

Comment: Did you check this repo: https://github.com/Morglod/tsee

Comment: I did not, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like the functionality that you can get from getting this sort of extension right. Anyhow, here are some ideas I would like to share that might help:

1. Depending on you intention here, maybe not implementing the interface is a good idea, but defining an abstract class that will extend the event emitter only, like so:

```
interface EventEmitterEvents {
    [event: string]: any[];
}
abstract class EventEmitterType<T extends EventEmitterEvents> extends EventEmitter {
    protected constructor() {
        super();

        // do stuff here
    }
    addListener<K extends keyof T | symbol>(event: K, listener: (...args: T[Extract<string, K>]) => void) {
        // do stuff here
        return super.addListener(event, listener);
    }
    on<K extends keyof T | symbol>(event: K, listener: (...args: T[Extract<string, K>]) => void) {
        // do stuff here
        return super.on(event, listener);
    }
}
class Hello extends EventEmitterType<{ hi: [string] }> {}
```

2. Bootstrapping the event emitter with the functionality that you
   want instead of extending the class like this.

```
/*
 * So the idea is to define a function that will convert the event emitter to your
 * desired design by strapping on the new stuff and ideas that you have.
 */

// So we have our interface from your sample code
interface EventEmitterEvents {
    [event: string]: any[];
}

interface EventEmitterType<T extends EventEmitterEvents> {
    addListener<K extends keyof T>(event: K, listener: (...args: T[K]) => void): this;
    on<K extends keyof T>(event: K, listener: (...args: T[K]) => void): this;
    ...
}

// then you define a function that will cast your interface onto the event emitter
function bootstrap<T extends EventEmitterEvents>(emitter: EventEmitter) {
  return emitter as EventEmitterType<T>
}
// this introduces a grey area in your code that you might not like though.
```

I hope this is of some use to your goal here.

Comment: Here you can find some typings for pub/sub pattern https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe narrowing the type of event names to `string` like `Extract<keyof T, string>` could help.

Or if you just want the result of `keyof` operator to be a string, add configuration with `"keyofStringsOnly": true` in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: This still wouldn't fix the problem. I edited my question to clarify this.